# Matlab load file in path of script

Tags: matlab, relative-path

I have a matlab script that wants to `load` a `.mat` file that is in a directory fixed *relative to the location of the script*. The script itself could be in different places relative to the current working directory, so the location of the `.mat` file is not known relative to it. How do I specify the location of the file to load relative to the script that is executing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`mfilename`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mfilename.html) returns the name of the **currently running script**.  This however does not return the full path to the script.  You probably want this and so you can specify the `'fullpath'` option to return the full path to the actual script itself, including the name of the script.

You just want the actual directory of where the file is, and so first use `mfilename` to get the full path to the actual file, then use [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) to actually extract the actual directory of where the file is.  `fileparts` returns the directory of where the file is, the file name itself and the extension.  You just want the first output argument and don't care about the other outputs.  Once you have this, you can then use the actual directory then append this string with the location of your `.mat` file:

```
p = mfilename('fullpath');
[pathstr,~,~] = fileparts(p);
d = fullfile(pathstr, 'path', 'to', 'your', 'file.mat');
```

[`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) builds a directory string that is OS independent, so for each subdirectory you want to indicate to get to your `.mat` file, place these as separate input strings up until you reach the file you want.  `d` will contain the full path of your `.mat` file relative to the currently running script, which you can then use to `load` accordingly.